# Android sdk not found in React native

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I have done all the set up for Android and iOS in React Native from below link in my mac mashine.

```
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/android-setup.html
```

Project created successfully. But when I tried to run the Android project using following command in my terminal:

```
react-native run-android
```

I am getting the below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > The SDK directory '/usr/local/opt/android-sdk' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.645 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

IO have copy the sdk firl to respectrive directory

```
'/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

But didnot over ride from the error.

Comment: Do you have Android SDK path in `ANDROID_HOME` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please create a file named `local.properties` inside your project's android folder and add the below line to it and save it.

```
sdk.dir={PATH OF YOUR ANDROID SDK}
```

After adding this file run again it will work properly.